# Why is limit of this function infinity as x approaches infinity?

Tags: limits, functions

I typed this function into symbolab and I got the next answer:
[image]

Why is the limit of the function as x approaches infinity even possible to calculate if we get beyond the domain of the function? How does this online calculator process $\sqrt{-∞}$?

Comment: Since you have the square root of a negative number, I guess this limit is taken in the complex numbers, where $\lim a_n = \infty$ iff $\lim |a_n| = \infty$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x+sqrt(2-x)+as+x+approaches+infinity

Comment: Yes! Wolframalpha makes it clear we are dealing with complex numbers and symbolab doesn't. Thank you for yousr insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online calculator is correct if you regard the complex plane as being completed by a single point $\infty$, but is wrong if you view $\infty$ as being a set of complex numbers with phase (as Mathematica does, for example).

The most unambiguous way to express the answer is probably "infinity, approached along the positive imaginary axis".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I got confused because symbolab doesn't mention complex numbers anywhere but this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

What is the domain of the function $f(x) = x \sqrt{2 - x}$?

Using local properties about limits,
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty \atop x > 2} f(x)\mbox{.}
$$
But $f\big|_{(2 , \infty)} : (2 , \infty) \to \{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re z = 0, Im z > 0\}$ is given by
$$
f\big|_{(2 , \infty)}(x) = x \sqrt{x - 2} i\mbox{.}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!